# How to stop android studio auto import to start from "file://..." for Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, import, flutter-dependencies

When I try to move files from one directory to another, Android studio auto-search and changes imports of that file in other files which is really convenient.

But in Flutter when I do this it starts the file import from `"file//...path"` in place of `"package:...path"`

i.e

```
import 'file:///C:/Users/my_name/AndroidStudioProjects/path-to-file/newpage_component.dart';
```

in place of

```
import 'package:path-to-file/newpage_component.dart';
```

This is really annoying and I have to change it in every file manually.

The biggest problem arises if you are using `build_runner` lib. It doesn't run `watch` command if there is any import starting from 'file://'

Answer (score 0):

Update Android Studio. Then update your Flutter and Dart plugins. Click `Help` > `Check for updates`.

Comment: Did this work for you? I have updated to latest plugins and android-studio version but still, the problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was fixed in March 2021 in this issue: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/43602
But according to the dart plugin version history https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart/versions, it's only compatible with Studio `build 211.6556+`.

The latest Studio release candidate is `build 202.7231092`

The latest Canary is `Arctic Fox 2020.3.1.14`

I don't know Studio's new naming scheme relates to the build numbers listed on the Jetbrains plugin page, but certainly for now it seems we can't get the update.